# Ruby on Rails Forms: how to create a CheckBox Table (or List)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, checkbox

What's the best way to create a related set of checkboxes in Ruby on Rails?  In the ToscaWidgets library used by Turbogears you can do the following:

```
 twf.CheckBoxTable('arbitrary_numbers', 
         num_cols=5, 
         options=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10']),
```

This generates 10 labeled checkboxes in two rows of 5 checkboxes.  I'm trying to duplicate this in Rails without just creating 10 separate checkbox controls.  No big deal, just hoping for a clean way to do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<% 10.times do |i| %>
  <%= label_tag i %>:
  <%= check_box_tag "alternate_numbers[#{i}]" %> <br />
<% end %>
```

will produce 10 checkboxes and if you will put it into form and submit it, you will have access to it in `params[:alternate_numbers][index]` where number is your number. You can put it into helper and call many times. You can also add some parameters to helper to customize output.

Comment: Thank you, that gives me a great starting point!  My actual issue is not so perfectly linear and sequential, but that shows me the right direction.